# NLTK data download hangs on MacOS in Anaconda environment

Tags: macos, download, nltk, macos-mojave

Running the following in a fresh `jupyter notebook` session or straight from the commandline:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

freezes the MacOS login session and requires repeated login instead of popping up UI for choosing the data packages needed.

Environment:

- miniconda install (anaconda 4.7.12; python 3.7.4.final).
- NLTK v. 3.4.5
- macOS Mojave v. 10.14.6
- jupyter-core v. 4.6.1
- notebook v. 6.0.2

How to workaround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that similar (however not as severe) problems led to the following question: [nltk.download() hangs on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598830/nltk-download-hangs-on-os-x)

The solution was both in the above case and the referred case to use a shell download UI instead of graphical interface that `nltk.download()` is supposed to open:

```
import nltk
nltk.download_shell()
```